# Change Array without returning it [C]

Tags: c, arrays, function

I just have a basic question concerning arrays in functions.
I am trying to change an array in a function without returning it.
I know how to do this for integers or doubles but i didn't know how to do this for arrays. So i experimented a little bit and now I am confused.

I have 2 variations of my code which i thought should do the same thing , but they don't. I pass the array b to the function Test. In the function I try to fill the array with the values 0, 1 ,2

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void Test(int * vector){
    vector = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        *(vector+i)=i;
    }

}

int main(){
    int b[3];
    Test(b);
    printf("%i\n",b[0]);
    printf("%i\n",b[1]);
    printf("%i\n",b[2]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This Version doesnt work, i don't get the expected result 0,1,2
This Code on the other hand does seem to work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void Test(int * vector){
    int * b = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    *(b+i)=i;
    *(vector+i) = *(b+i);
    }


}

int main(){
    int b[3];
    Test(b);
    printf("%i, ",b[0]);
    printf("%i, ",b[1]);
    printf("%i ",b[2]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Can somebody explain to me why only the second one works?

Best Regards,
Rob

Comment: `for (int i=0;i<3;i++) vector[i]=i;` is the correct code. You've allocated memory for the array on the stack in `main`. So all you need to do is fill in the values.

Comment: `vector = malloc(3*sizeof(int));` overwrites the `vector` parameter with a pointer to a new, unrelated block of memory. If you want to fill the memory pointed to by the original `vector`, don’t throw away that pointer. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an array to a function, it decays into a pointer to the first element.  That's what the function sees.  But then you take the function parameter `vector` and overwrite it with dynamically allocated memory.  Then you don't have access to the array you passed in.  Additionally, you have a memory leak because you didn't free the allocated memory.

In the case of the second function you don't modify `vector`, so when you dereference the pointer you're changing `b` in main.

Also, instead of this:

```
*(vector+i)
```

Use this:

```
vector[i]
```

It's much clearer to the reader what it means.

Comment: @Rob Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

`test` doesn't need to call `malloc()`. When you use an array as a function argument, it passes a pointer to the array. So you can simply write into `vector[i]` and it will modify the caller's array.

```
void Test(int * vector){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        *(vector+i)=i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it a lot more complicated than it is I guess.